# swashbuckle generates invalid field names

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

It's seems like swashbuckle (5.2.2) generates invalid fieldnames. I have a model that (partly) looks like this, all properties have a backing field with the suffix "Field"

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true,
    Namespace = "http://SomeCompany.Web.Service")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://SomeCompany.Web.Service", IsNullable = false)
]
public partial class GetOrderLines
{

    private string orderNumberField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public string OrderNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.orderNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.orderNumberField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The controller method signature looks like this:

```
public GetOrderLinesResponse Get([FromUri]GetOrderLines request)
{

}
```

The generated documentation looks like this:

[image]

It's is using the names of the private fields instead of using the names of the properties. Is this expected behaviour? Is there any way I can work around this and get the actual property instead?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and was solved by an answer to a related question -https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725054/1462905.

The short answer is that Json.NET does something different for classes that are marked `Serializable`.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
{
    IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true
};
```