# web.api only serializing hidden fields

Tags: codefluent

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour. 
My web.api is returning only hiddenfields from my ObjectCollection on a GET request.
This is my controller:

```
// GET: api/UserDocuments
[Route("api/UserDocuments/User/{userName}")]
public List<DocIndex> Get(string userName)
{
    User usuari = Humanisme.User.LoadByUserName(userName);
    List<DocIndex> resposta = DocumentCollection.LoadIndexPerUsuari(usuari);
    return resposta;
}
```

And this is the object as it gets generated from the BOM:

```
    namespace Humanisme
    {
    using CodeFluent.Runtime;
    using CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities;


    // CodeFluent Entities generated (http://www.softfluent.com). Date: Tuesday, 01 March 2016 11:52.
    // Build:1.0.61214.0820
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CodeFluent Entities", "1.0.61214.0820")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectAttribute()]
    public partial class DocIndex : CodeFluent.Runtime.ICodeFluentLightEntity
    {

        private int _id = -1;

        [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
        private Humanisme.User _user = ((Humanisme.User)(null));

        private string _lat = default(string);

        private string _lon = default(string);

        private string _etapaVital = default(string);

        private string _solvencia = default(string);

        private int _valoracio = CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultInt32Value;

        private System.DateTime _data = CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultDateTimeValue;

        private string _nom = default(string);

        public DocIndex()
        {
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(((int)(-1)))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=false, Type=typeof(int))]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectFieldAttribute(true)]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._id;
            }
            set
            {
                this._id = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public Humanisme.User User
        {
            get
            {
                return this._user;
            }
            set
            {
                this._user = value;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(default(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Type=typeof(string))]
        public string Lat
        {
            get
            {
                return this._lat;
            }
            set
            {
                this._lat = value;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(default(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Type=typeof(string))]
        public string Lon
        {
            get
            {
                return this._lon;
            }
            set
            {
                this._lon = value;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(default(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Type=typeof(string))]
        public string EtapaVital
        {
            get
            {
                return this._etapaVital;
            }
            set
            {
                this._etapaVital = value;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(default(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Type=typeof(string))]
        public string Solvencia
        {
            get
            {
                return this._solvencia;
            }
            set
            {
                this._solvencia = value;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultInt32Value)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=false, Type=typeof(int))]
        public int Valoracio
        {
            get
            {
                return this._valoracio;
            }
            set
            {
                this._valoracio = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=false, Type=typeof(System.DateTime))]
        public System.DateTime Data
        {
            get
            {
                return this._data;
            }
            set
            {
                this._data = value;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(default(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Type=typeof(string))]
        public string Nom
        {
            get
            {
                return this._nom;
            }
            set
            {
                this._nom = value;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void ReadRecord(System.Data.IDataReader reader, CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentReloadOptions options)
        {
            if ((reader == null))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("reader");
            }
            if ((((options & CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentReloadOptions.Properties) 
                        == 0) 
                        == false))
            {
                this._id = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "Id", ((int)(-1)));
                this._user = new Humanisme.User();
                CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentLightWeightPersistence.ReadRecord(reader, this._user, null, new CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.Pair<string, string>("Id", "User_Id"));
                this._lat = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "Lat", ((string)(default(string))));
                this._lon = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "Lon", ((string)(default(string))));
                this._etapaVital = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "EtapaVital", ((string)(default(string))));
                this._solvencia = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "Solvencia", ((string)(default(string))));
                this._valoracio = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "Valoracio", ((int)(CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultInt32Value)));
                this._data = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "Data", ((System.DateTime)(CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultDateTimeValue)));
                this._nom = CodeFluentPersistence.GetReaderValue(reader, "Nom", ((string)(default(string))));
            }
        }

        void CodeFluent.Runtime.ICodeFluentLightEntity.ReadRecord(System.Data.IDataReader reader)
        {
            this.ReadRecord(reader, CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentReloadOptions.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the web.api get method returns this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "_lat": null,
    "_lon": null,
    "_etapaVital": null,
    "_solvencia": null,
    "_valoracio": 0,
    "_data": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "_nom": null
  }
]
```

Serializer (from WebApiConfig.cs)

```
JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = (JsonMediaTypeFormatter)config.Formatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f is JsonMediaTypeFormatter);
        if (jsonFormatter != null)
        {
           // jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
            jsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
        }
```

Comment: Which JSON serializer are you using?

Comment: Hy meziantou. I've updated with the webapiconfig.cs part about the serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found!

When dealing with web.api never, never, never forget to add the "Service Producer" subproducer attached to the standard BOM Producer in your model project.

You'll never notice any problem but at serializing when no attributes will be processed and only hidden properties (object fields) will be serialized at output.

Sorry for the nerd mistake, happy for the lesson learned.

Again, thanks Meziantou. You would never figured where the issue was originated, mainly because I didn't carried all the project details to the question.

Comment: The Service Producer is not mandatory to use `WebAPI` and `Json.NET`. This producer adds the `DataMemberAttribute` which can be used by the serializer. However you can also use the [aspect provided on GitHub](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/tree/master/Extensions/SoftFluent.Json.NET) which adds Json.NET specific attributes.

Answer (score 3):

The classes generated by CodeFluent Entities are decorated by `SerializableAttribute`. This attribute changes the way `Json.NET` serialize or deserialize the object. You can configure `Json.NET` to ignore this attribute:

```
JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = (JsonMediaTypeFormatter)config.Formatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f is JsonMediaTypeFormatter);
if (jsonFormatter != null)
{
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
    {
        IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true
    };
}
```

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/04/11/json-net-4-5-release-2-serializable-support-and-bug-fixes

> Json.NET now detects types that have the SerializableAttribute and serializes all the fields on that type, both public and private, and ignores the propertie

So you can use the service producer which will add the `DataMemberAttribute` or you can use the [`Json.NET Aspect`](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/tree/master/Extensions/SoftFluent.Json.NET) to automatically add specific Json.NET attribute: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObjectAttribute` and `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute`.

Comment: No way, meziantou. It's still serializing only hidden fields from my entity...
Wondering about it may be any CodeFluent project property from advanced tabs.

Comment: Did you remove `UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true`?

Comment: Yes. I tried removing everything but your code. I've been checking with other web.api project at global.asax and startup classes and everything is exactly the same. Even copied/pasted to avoid typos...

Comment: What's really strange is that it outputs all private fields and avoids public properties of the entity; not only in this entity, every object instance in the model is returned showing only private fields in place of public properties.